# Elasticsearch 1.7.1 not creating a snapshot, but not reporting error either

Tags: elasticsearch, snapshot

I'm trying to create a snapshot of all indexes in my local Elasticsearch instance.

I've set path.repo as follows in elasticsearch.yml:

```
path.repo: ["F:\\backup\\elasticsearch"]
```

And here's the command I'm using to create the snapshot:

```
curl -XPUT http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_test_backup -d '
{
    "type": "fs",
        "settings": {
        "location": "F:\\backup\\elasticsearch\\my_test_backup" 
    }
}'
```

Executing this generates the following output from Elasticsearch:

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   136  100    21  100   115    269   1474 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1854{"acknowledged":true}
```

Note, no error.

There are a couple of indexes set up on my local instance, which aren't particularly large so, when I check the snapshot status, it shows no in progress snapshots:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_snapshot/_status
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100    16  100    16    0     0   1000      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1000{"snapshots":[]}
```

As I say, this isn't necessarily a worry because the snapshot would be small anyway. I can see the snapshot I've just created by executing the following, but it appears to have hung:

```
$ curl -XGET http://localhost:9200/_snapshot
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   100  100   100    0     0    100      0  0:00:01 --:--:--  0:00:01   97k{"my_test_backup":{"type":"fs","settings":{"location":"F:\\backup\\elasticsearch\\my_test_backup"}}}
```

Consistent with this, when I navigate to *F:\backup\elasticsearch\my_test_backup* the folder is empty.

Could somebody tell me why my snapshot isn't working? What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks,

Bart

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All you have done there is to create a repository, not a snapshot. Creating a repository is a necessary artifact that will store all future snapshots you will create.

So now that you have your repository, you can simply kick off the [snapshot creation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.4/modules-snapshots.html#_snapshot) as follows:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_test_backup/snapshot_1"
```

If you run the following command instead, it will only return when the snapshot is done:

```
curl -XPUT "localhost:9200/_snapshot/my_test_backup/snapshot_1?wait_for_completion=true"
```

Comment: Thanks Val - knew it would be my bad. I was looking at this a few weeks back, then had to move on, came back to it yesterday and didn't re-read the docs nearly carefully enough, and spent too much time googling for a solution to a non-problem. I imagine this answer is correct but I'm back on elasticsearch this afternoon so will try it out before I mark it as such. Thanks again!

Comment: Great, this worked: thanks Val. I've just found a handy tool called curator which might help with snapshots, and cleaning them up after.